Replace complex pattern in big expression in a non-sensitive way
Assume this big expression
expr = {(((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*Subscript[b, 2] + 
    (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*((-(alp2*alp3) + bet2)*Subscript[b, 1] + 
    (-1 + alp3*bet1)*Subscript[b, 2] + (alp2 - bet1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   Subscript[ep, 2]*(Subscript[ep, 2] - Subscript[ep, 3])*Subscript[ep, 3]*
   ((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
    (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (-1 + alp3*bet1 + alp1*(-(alp2*alp3) + bet2) + alp2*bet3 - bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   2, (((-1 + alp2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1 - bet1*bet3)*
     Subscript[b, 2] + (-(alp1*alp2) + bet1)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[b, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[b, 2] + 
    (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 1]*
   (Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 2])*Subscript[ep, 2]*
   ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
     Subscript[ep, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (-1 + alp3*bet1 + alp1*(-(alp2*alp3) + bet2) + alp2*bet3 - bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   2, -((((-1 + alp2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1 - bet1*bet3)*
      Subscript[b, 2] + (-(alp1*alp2) + bet1)*Subscript[b, 3])*
    ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
      Subscript[b, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 1]*
    (Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 3])*Subscript[ep, 3]*
    ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
     (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
   (-1 + alp3*bet1 + alp1*(-(alp2*alp3) + bet2) + alp2*bet3 - bet1*bet2*bet3)^
    2), (-2*bet2*((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + 
    (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*Subscript[b, 2] + (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[b, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[b, 2] + 
    (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 1]*
   (Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 2])*((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*
     Subscript[ep, 3])*((alp3 - bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (-(alp1*alp3) + bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (-1 + alp1*bet2)*
     Subscript[ep, 3]))/(1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - 
    alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^3, 
 (alp1*((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[b, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*
      Subscript[b, 2] + (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])^2*
   (Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 2])*Subscript[ep, 2]*
   ((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
    (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*Subscript[ep, 3])*
   ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
     Subscript[ep, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   3, ((Subscript[b, 1] - Subscript[b, 2])*
   ((-(alp2*alp3) + bet2)*Subscript[b, 1] + (-1 + alp3*bet1)*
     Subscript[b, 2] + (alp2 - bet1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 1]*
   Subscript[ep, 2]*((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*
     Subscript[ep, 3])*((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (-1 + alp3*bet1 + alp1*(-(alp2*alp3) + bet2) + alp2*bet3 - bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   2, (-2*alp3*((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + 
    (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*Subscript[b, 2] + (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
     Subscript[b, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 1]*
   (Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 3])*((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*
     Subscript[ep, 3])*((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   3, (bet1*((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + 
     (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*Subscript[b, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])^2*
   (Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 3])*Subscript[ep, 3]*
   ((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
    (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*Subscript[ep, 3])*
   ((-(alp2*alp3) + bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (-1 + alp3*bet1)*
     Subscript[ep, 2] + (alp2 - bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   3, ((Subscript[b, 1] - Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((alp3 - bet2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (-(alp1*alp3) + bet3)*
     Subscript[b, 2] + (-1 + alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 1]*
   Subscript[ep, 3]*((-1 + alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (alp1 - bet1*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (-(alp1*alp2) + bet1)*
     Subscript[ep, 3])*((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (-1 + alp3*bet1 + alp1*(-(alp2*alp3) + bet2) + alp2*bet3 - bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   2, -((bet3*((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[b, 1] + 
      (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[b, 2] + (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])^
     2*Subscript[ep, 2]*(Subscript[ep, 2] - Subscript[ep, 3])*
    ((-1 + alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (alp1 - bet1*bet3)*
      Subscript[ep, 2] + (-(alp1*alp2) + bet1)*Subscript[ep, 3])*
    ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
      Subscript[ep, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
   (1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^
    3), (2*alp2*((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + 
    (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*Subscript[b, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[b, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[b, 2] + 
    (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*(Subscript[ep, 2] - 
    Subscript[ep, 3])*Subscript[ep, 3]*((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*
     Subscript[ep, 3])*((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   3, ((Subscript[b, 2] - Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((-(alp2*alp3) + bet2)*Subscript[b, 1] + (-1 + alp3*bet1)*
     Subscript[b, 2] + (alp2 - bet1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 2]*
   Subscript[ep, 3]*((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*
     Subscript[ep, 3])*((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (-1 + alp3*bet1 + alp1*(-(alp2*alp3) + bet2) + alp2*bet3 - bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   2, -((alp3*((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*
       Subscript[b, 2] + (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*Subscript[b, 3])^2*
    Subscript[ep, 1]*(Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 3])*
    ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
      Subscript[ep, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3])*
    ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
     (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
   (1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^
    3), (2*bet1*((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + 
    (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*Subscript[b, 2] + (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
     Subscript[b, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   (Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 3])*Subscript[ep, 3]*
   ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
     Subscript[ep, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3])*
   ((-(alp2*alp3) + bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (-1 + alp3*bet1)*
     Subscript[ep, 2] + (alp2 - bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   3, -(((Subscript[b, 1] - Subscript[b, 3])*
    ((-1 + alp2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1 - bet1*bet3)*Subscript[b, 2] + 
     (-(alp1*alp2) + bet1)*Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 3]*
    ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
      Subscript[ep, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3])*
    ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
     (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
   (-1 + alp3*bet1 + alp1*(-(alp2*alp3) + bet2) + alp2*bet3 - bet1*bet2*bet3)^
    2), (-2*bet3*((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + 
    (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*Subscript[b, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[b, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[b, 2] + 
    (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 2]*
   (Subscript[ep, 2] - Subscript[ep, 3])*((-1 + alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (alp1 - bet1*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (-(alp1*alp2) + bet1)*
     Subscript[ep, 3])*((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   3, (alp2*((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + 
     (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*Subscript[b, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])^2*
   (Subscript[ep, 2] - Subscript[ep, 3])*Subscript[ep, 3]*
   ((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
    (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*Subscript[ep, 3])*
   ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
    (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   3, ((Subscript[b, 2] - Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
     Subscript[b, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 2]*
   Subscript[ep, 3]*((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*
     Subscript[ep, 3])*((-(alp2*alp3) + bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (-1 + alp3*bet1)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (alp2 - bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (-1 + alp3*bet1 + alp1*(-(alp2*alp3) + bet2) + alp2*bet3 - bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   2, (bet2*((-1 + alp2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1 - bet1*bet3)*
      Subscript[b, 2] + (-(alp1*alp2) + bet1)*Subscript[b, 3])^2*
   Subscript[ep, 1]*(Subscript[ep, 1] - Subscript[ep, 2])*
   ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
     Subscript[ep, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3])*
   ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
    (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   3, (2*alp1*((1 - alp2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (-alp1 + bet1*bet3)*
     Subscript[b, 2] + (alp1*alp2 - bet1)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[b, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[b, 2] + 
    (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*(Subscript[ep, 1] - 
    Subscript[ep, 2])*Subscript[ep, 2]*
   ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
     Subscript[ep, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3])*
   ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
    (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   3, ((Subscript[b, 1] - Subscript[b, 2])*
   ((-1 + alp2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1 - bet1*bet3)*Subscript[b, 2] + 
    (-(alp1*alp2) + bet1)*Subscript[b, 3])*Subscript[ep, 1]*Subscript[ep, 2]*
   ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
     Subscript[ep, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3])*
   ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
    (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3]))/
  (-1 + alp3*bet1 + alp1*(-(alp2*alp3) + bet2) + alp2*bet3 - bet1*bet2*bet3)^
   2, (((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
     Subscript[b, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[b, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[b, 2] + 
    (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*((-1 + alp2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + 
    (alp1 - bet1*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2] + (-(alp1*alp2) + bet1)*
     Subscript[ep, 3])*(Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3]*
     ((alp1*(-1 + alp3*(-1 + 2*bet1) + bet2) + bet1*(-1 + alp3 - bet2)*bet3)*
       Subscript[ep, 2] + (alp1*alp2*(1 + alp3 - bet2) - 2*alp1*bet1*bet2 + 
        bet1*(1 - alp3 + bet2))*Subscript[ep, 3]) + 
    Subscript[ep, 1]^2*(((-1 + alp2 - bet1)*bet2*bet3 + 
        alp3*(-1 + bet1 + alp2*(-1 + 2*bet3)))*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
      (alp2*alp3*(1 + alp1 - bet3) - 2*alp2*bet2*bet3 + 
        bet2*(1 - alp1 + bet3))*Subscript[ep, 3]) + 
    Subscript[ep, 1]*((alp1*alp3*(1 + alp2 - bet1) + 
        (1 - alp2 + bet1 - 2*alp3*bet1)*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2]^2 + 
      (alp1 + alp2 + alp3 - bet1 - alp1*alp3*bet1 - bet2 + alp1*bet1*bet2 - 
        alp1*alp2*(3*alp3 + bet2) - bet3 + alp2*(-alp3 + bet2)*bet3 + 
        bet1*(alp3 + 3*bet2)*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3] + 
      (bet1*bet2*(-1 + alp1 - bet3) + alp2*(-1 - alp1 + 2*alp1*bet2 + bet3))*
       Subscript[ep, 3]^2)))/(1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - 
    alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^3, 
 (((-1 + alp2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1 - bet1*bet3)*Subscript[b, 2] + 
    (-(alp1*alp2) + bet1)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[b, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[b, 2] + 
    (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
     Subscript[ep, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3])*
   (Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3]*
     ((alp1*(-1 + alp3*(-1 + 2*bet1) + bet2) + bet1*(-1 + alp3 - bet2)*bet3)*
       Subscript[ep, 2] + (alp1*alp2*(1 + alp3 - bet2) - 2*alp1*bet1*bet2 + 
        bet1*(1 - alp3 + bet2))*Subscript[ep, 3]) + 
    Subscript[ep, 1]^2*(((-1 + alp2 - bet1)*bet2*bet3 + 
        alp3*(-1 + bet1 + alp2*(-1 + 2*bet3)))*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
      (alp2*alp3*(1 + alp1 - bet3) - 2*alp2*bet2*bet3 + 
        bet2*(1 - alp1 + bet3))*Subscript[ep, 3]) + 
    Subscript[ep, 1]*((alp1*alp3*(1 + alp2 - bet1) + 
        (1 - alp2 + bet1 - 2*alp3*bet1)*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2]^2 + 
      (alp1 + alp2 + alp3 - bet1 - alp1*alp3*bet1 - bet2 + alp1*bet1*bet2 - 
        alp1*alp2*(3*alp3 + bet2) - bet3 + alp2*(-alp3 + bet2)*bet3 + 
        bet1*(alp3 + 3*bet2)*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3] + 
      (bet1*bet2*(-1 + alp1 - bet3) + alp2*(-1 - alp1 + 2*alp1*bet2 + bet3))*
       Subscript[ep, 3]^2)))/(1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - 
    alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^3, 
 (((-1 + alp2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1 - bet1*bet3)*Subscript[b, 2] + 
    (-(alp1*alp2) + bet1)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*Subscript[b, 1] + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*
     Subscript[b, 2] + (1 - alp1*bet2)*Subscript[b, 3])*
   ((alp2*alp3 - bet2)*Subscript[ep, 1] + (1 - alp3*bet1)*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
    (-alp2 + bet1*bet2)*Subscript[ep, 3])*
   (Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3]*
     ((alp1*(-1 + alp3*(-1 + 2*bet1) + bet2) + bet1*(-1 + alp3 - bet2)*bet3)*
       Subscript[ep, 2] + (alp1*alp2*(1 + alp3 - bet2) - 2*alp1*bet1*bet2 + 
        bet1*(1 - alp3 + bet2))*Subscript[ep, 3]) + 
    Subscript[ep, 1]^2*(((-1 + alp2 - bet1)*bet2*bet3 + 
        alp3*(-1 + bet1 + alp2*(-1 + 2*bet3)))*Subscript[ep, 2] + 
      (alp2*alp3*(1 + alp1 - bet3) - 2*alp2*bet2*bet3 + 
        bet2*(1 - alp1 + bet3))*Subscript[ep, 3]) + 
    Subscript[ep, 1]*((alp1*alp3*(1 + alp2 - bet1) + 
        (1 - alp2 + bet1 - 2*alp3*bet1)*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2]^2 + 
      (alp1 + alp2 + alp3 - bet1 - alp1*alp3*bet1 - bet2 + alp1*bet1*bet2 - 
        alp1*alp2*(3*alp3 + bet2) - bet3 + alp2*(-alp3 + bet2)*bet3 + 
        bet1*(alp3 + 3*bet2)*bet3)*Subscript[ep, 2]*Subscript[ep, 3] + 
      (bet1*bet2*(-1 + alp1 - bet3) + alp2*(-1 - alp1 + 2*alp1*bet2 + bet3))*
       Subscript[ep, 3]^2)))/(1 + alp1*alp2*alp3 - alp3*bet1 - alp1*bet2 - 
    alp2*bet3 + bet1*bet2*bet3)^3}

In expr, I would like to replace automatically any expression of the form (for instance) :
(-alp3 + bet2*bet3)*x1__ + (alp1*alp3 - bet3)*x2__ + 
(1 - alp1*bet2)*x3__ 

by
vk12.{x1,x2,x3}

(this implies that
vk12        = {alp3 - bet2*bet3, -(alp1*alp3) + bet3, -1 + alp1*bet2}

)
Set :
vk13        = {alp2*alp3 - bet2, 1 - alp3*bet1, -alp2 + bet1*bet2}
vk23        = {-1 + alp2*bet3, alp1 - bet1*bet3, -(alp1*alp2) + bet1}

Likewise I would like to replace any expression in expr of the form (for instance)
 (1 - alp3*bet1) x2__ + (alp2*alp3 - bet2) x1__ + (-alp2 + bet1*bet2) x3__

by
vk13.{x1,x2,x3}

and
(bet1*bet3-alp1) x2__ + (1 - alp2*bet3) x1__ + ((alp1*alp2) - bet1) x3__

by
vk23.{x1,x2,x3}

and {x1,x2,x3} is a suitable vector, for instance
{x1,x2,x3}={Subscript[b, 1],Subscript[b, 2],Subscript[b, 3]}


For instance, I tried this :
(Numerator /@ # /. {(alp3 - bet2*bet3) x1__ + (-(alp1*alp3) + bet3) x2__ + (-1 + alp1*bet2) x3__ :> vk12.{x1,x2,x3}})/Denominator[#[[1]]] & /@  GatherBy[List@@expr, Denominator]

but it is too sensitive (for instance if in expr we have :
(-alp3 + bet2*bet3) x1 + (-bet3 + (alp1*alp3)) x2 + (1 - alp1*bet2) x3

it won't do anything.
Do I need to detail more what I want or is it clear ?

ReplaceAll does no arithmetic, it works only on the structure (of FullForm). E.g. the following does not work
(-a + b) x1 /. (a - b) x__ :> coef  x1

(-a + b) x1

only the following does:
(a - b) x1 /. (a - b) x__ :> coef  x1

coef x1

This is the reason that the replacement on:
(-alp3 + bet2*bet3) x1 + (-bet3 + (alp1*alp3)) x2 + (1 - alp1*bet2) x3

does not work. The same with your long expression.

@The down-voter: It is not fair to down vote without any explaining comment.
